QAbstractListModel makes QPushButton unclickable
I am writing an app using Model View Controller Architecture. App consists of two windows: main window has only one button, click on which opens another window. Another window consists of QListView and a QPushButton (addFitsBtn). QAbstractListModel is used to display the data in QListView. However, when I use the QAbstractListModel to populate the QListView, QPushButton (addFitsBtn) becomes unclickable and I constantly see following error:
UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'fit_item' where it is not associated with a value
Commenting the following line in controller.py returns clickability of the button, but then I can not use the QAbstractListModel to display my data. Any suggestions how can I sort this out?
#self._window.listAvailFits.setModel(self._model)

Structure of the package:
app
|--__init__.py
|--mvc
|  |--__init__.py
|  |--view.py
|  |--controller.py
|  |--model.py-
|--app.py

Here is view.py:
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QWidget, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QListView

class AnotherWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.addFitsBtn = QPushButton("&Add Fit(s)")
        self.listAvailFits = QListView()
        layout.addWidget(self.listAvailFits)
        layout.addWidget(self.addFitsBtn)
        self.setLayout(layout)

class MainUI(QMainWindow):
    """View initializer"""
    def __init__(self):
        """
        GUI initializer.
        """
        super().__init__()
        self.btn = QPushButton("&Test")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.btn)

    def showAnotherWindow(self):
        self.w = AnotherWindow()
        return self.w

    def toggleAnotherWindow(self):
        if self.w.isVisible():
            self.w.hide()
        else:
            self.w.show()

controller.py
from .model import Model
from functools import partial
class Cntrl():
    def __init__(self, view_main):
        self._view_main = view_main
        self._window = self._view_main.showAnotherWindow()
        self._view_main.btn.clicked.connect(partial(self._display_data))

    def _display_data(self):
        data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        self._model = Model(data)
        self._window.listAvailFits.setModel(self._model)
        self._view_main.toggleAnotherWindow()

model.py
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt, QAbstractListModel

class Model(QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, avail_fits=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.avail_fits = avail_fits or []

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            fit_item = self.avail_fits[index.row()]
        return fit_item

    def rowCount(self, index):
        return len(self.avail_fits)

app.py

from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication
import sys
from mvc.view import MainUI
from mvc.controller import Cntrl
def main():
    app = QApplication([])
    view_main = MainUI()
    view_main.show()
    Cntrl(view_main=view_main)
    sys.exit(app.exec())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


The error is clear: if the if clause isn't met, fit_item is not defined, so return fit_item is invalid. Remove that last line in data() and replace the second with return self.avail_fits[index.row()]. You should also change to ctrl = Cntrl(view_main=view_main) to avoid possible garbage collection. Finally, while the MVC pattern is perfectly valid, it should only be used when really necessary. Most of the times, especially with simple Qt apps, it's not, and it's an unnecessary complication. For more complex scenarios, the QApplication itself is often used as "controller".
